# Is it possible to fillOvals with different colors that are in a loop?

Tags: java

Im wondering if it is possible to fill ovals with different colors that are being drawn in a loop

```java
private void drawSirklar(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    int rad = 25;
    int dia = 50;
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        g.drawOval(250 - (i * rad), 250 - (i * rad), (i + 1) * dia, (i + 1) * dia);
    }
}
```

or if I have to draw each oval and fill them with color individually

What I'm trying to do is make an archery target

Comment: You would use the fillOval method and setColor for each circle you wish to draw.  Start with the largest circle first and work your way to the bullseye.

Comment: Yea, i thought i'd have to do that. Just thought it'd be very cool if it was possible to do it with a loop

Comment: You can do it in a loop.  Put the colors you want to use in an array.  Base the drawing of your ovals on a center point and radius.  Each time through the loop, reduce the radius and get the next color.